# ECS ASG scaling down policy recommendations

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-ecs

We're using **AWS ECS** to handle our services as a fleet of containers. The **EC2** instances, on which the **Docker/ECS** agents run, are in an auto-scaling group, whose number of instances is based on custom metrics to ensure we always globally have enough available memory to start a few containers at once, but not too much to limit the costs.

There are no issues when scaling up, but scaling down according to the available memory means that a server with running containers can get removed (and the containers arbitrarily killed).
It wasn't an issue until recently, because each critical service was running at least two tasks, so one task could be closed and could restart somewhere else without any service interruption.

But we now have services (*Jenkins* + remote slaves) that would better not get interrupted (or it may cut the slave -> master connection and make a job build crash).

I have a few ideas to try to handle that, but I'm wondering if there are recommandations, **AWS** options or a clever way to proceed to allow an **ECS** cluster to scale down while avoiding casualties...

Comment: The vital services, would you consider these an "always up" type of service?

Comment: @ChrisWhite "Vital" is a great word. That's not always up, in this specific case the Jenkins slave containers disappear at the end of a build job. But the idea is to ensure they don't disappear due to a scaling in operation.

Comment: we are having exact same problem. services which are running in low numbers say 1 or 2 get killed if ec2 scale scale down happens. ideally it should check if there are any tasks running in the ec2 instance and then procede  accordingly

Comment: @hannadrehman So I hope that my self-answer helped you (termination protection)... I've been using this solution for two years and didn't have any problem (or deadlock) so far. Fargate could also be a good way to get rid of that kind of concerns (didn't play with it yet, it's a bit more expensive than our home-made scaling group)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I added control over the autoscaling operations by playing with the **termination protection**.

Each **ECS** instance regularly runs a script that returns metrics.
In this script, I added the following part:

```
if [ $noContainersRunning == 1 ] && [ $asgProtection == true ]; then
    aws autoscaling set-instance-protection --region $region --instance-ids $instanceId --auto-scaling-group-name $asgId --no-protected-from-scale-in
    echo "Disabling scale-in protection"
elif  [ $noContainersRunning == 0 ] && [ $asgProtection == false ]; then
    aws autoscaling set-instance-protection --region $region --instance-ids $instanceId --auto-scaling-group-name $asgId --protected-from-scale-in
    echo "Enabling scale-in protection"
fi
```

(with `noContainerRunning` being a variable that contains 1 if no tasks are running on this instance, and `asgProtection` the current state of the termination protection on this instance)

Consequently, the auto-scaling group won't be able to remove an instance that contains a running container. If all instances run at least one container, the *desired* count will go down, but the auto-scaling will return *cancelled: could not scale* until an instance has 0 containers running again.

It's working quite well!

I also recreated the services with the **bin-pack** task placement template, to ensure the containers don't spread on all the instances of the cluster.

Answer (score -2):

I think you may want to consider [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/). Essentially you have:

- Compute Environments: Essentially EC2 instances which are carved up into containers. This scales up and down depending on what jobs need to be run on it.
- Job Queues: A way to assert task priority when deciding what resources in the compute environment should go to which job
- Job Definitions: Essentially describes what portion of your overall compute environment gets carved up. It also descries what the the actual compute work that needs to be done is.

Overall I would personally break up into two separate compute environments: one for the Jenkins work and one for the other work. Then assign job queues to each compute environment so you know where tasks need to go. When work in the queue related to a certain compute environment is done Batch can simply tear down the container hosting instance. Need to do the work again? It will spin resources up again for you. The nice thing here is that your teardown can be more focused on what work is done rather than OS resource metrics.

If you need to scale at some point, you can simply increase the compute environment, add more compute environments, adjust job definition resource specs, etc. There's also an option for utilizing spot instances for a bit better cost control.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already had a look at AWS Batch and am not so convinced, that's the kind of stuff (like lambdas) that runs over AWS containers infra, but it's really designed to run tasks. What we run are services such as a Subversion server, a NPM registry, websites, etc... Also, the objective is not to have someone running anything manually, the point is to avoid losing time in micromanagement. I'm looking, as told in my question, for something concerning the autoscaling of an ECS cluster.

Comment: @arvymetal you might want to add the specifics of the services in your question then. Seeing Jenkins in there made it seem like a sort of build system that gets activated given some conditions. Also the services you're listing sounds like things you'd want up constantly and it's hard to tell what the autoscaling conditions are (except web servers for additional load maybe).